# Vagrant up error on mac

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

```
Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:

id -u nginx

The error output from the command was:

id: nginx: no such user
```

Vagrant version : 1.9.1

Virtualbox version : 5.1.14

Already tried this and it didn't worked:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions

ln: /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions: File exists
```

Comment: install the [vagrant vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest)

Comment: Tried that as well, didn't worked

Comment: the second part of the error is about missing nginx user, do you create the user as part of your provisioning ? is it already available ?

Comment: you are also using guest additions in your box that are different to your virtual box version. Try a box file that has the same version of guest additions as the version of virtual box you are using.